# Laravel SFTP class not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I upgraded laravel to [V5.6.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v5.6.7) where sftp driver is included.

I have set my config in `config/filesystems.php`

```
'sftp' => [
    'driver'   => 'sftp',
    'host'     => 'myhost.com',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
],
```

And when I do

`dd( Storage::disk('sftp')->files('/') );`

This throw 
`Class 'League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter' not found`

And indeed, this class does not exist in my vendor folder.

But my `composer.json` is like this

```
{
    "require": {
        ....
        "laravel/framework": "~5.6.7",
        ....
},
```

And `composer update` tell me that everything is updated.

What should I do to get this class?

---

PS: When I dump another disk, it's working very well

Comment: Why did I get downvote 0.5 sec after my question was created? :'(

Comment: install `league/flysystem-sftp` package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the PR on github

> SFTP driver requires league/flysystem-sftp so it should be added to
>   composer file as in case of AWS or Rackspace drivers.

you need to do this

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp
```

[Instruction here](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp)

@Devon (thanks)

Also form [LARAVEL.COM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration)

> ```
> Driver Prerequisites
> Composer Packages
> Before using the SFTP, S3, or Rackspace drivers, you will need to install the appropriate package via Composer:
>
> SFTP: league/flysystem-sftp ~1.0
> Amazon S3: league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0
> Rackspace: league/flysystem-rackspace ~1.0
> ```

Comment: The Laravel docs also mention this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration

Comment: If someone gets error try:
composer require league/flysystem-sftp:*

Answer (score 0):

**Latest update**

v2 will not work with latest laravel version, it's deprecated and not maintained.

simply use v3 according to [official website](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp-v3/) and [github](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp-v3)

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp-v3
```